# Spring MVC and Ajax framework to use

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

I want to combine Spring MVC with AJAX capabilities in a Web application. I know that, for instance, DWR supports Spring by allowing you to expose Spring beans for remote invocation.

Is there a more suitable javascript framework to use when you are using Spring MVC as your Java Web framework?.

Comment: What do you mean by more suitable? Spring MVC itself can handle Ajax requests, so you can use a client side framework such as jQuery or Prototype too.

Comment: more suitable js framework will be the one you are most comfortable with :)

Comment: What you are using at server side is independent of what JS framework you are going to use. The server may have anything(PHP or Webservice or JSP or a plain HTML) when you are making AJAX. Take a look at jQuery AJAX.

Comment: I know I can use whatever JS framework I want from the client side (i'm a SCEA ;-). What I am asking here is if there is any JS framework with specific features/tools that make the use of it in conjunction with MVC Spring easier/friendlier. I want my application to be AJAX enabled but I would like to spend as little as possible tinkering with JS intricacies